# how to create a grapher below in processing

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, processing

I want to create a graph with nodes and lines that connect node around the circumference only

I tried this; it didn't work

```java
for (int i = 0; i < nodeX.length; i++) {
    fill(0);
    ellipse(nodeX[i], nodeY[i], 10, 10);
}
```

or a pass mark, there must be a display window of size (600, 360) containing a grid with the same number of columns and rows (10 in the video). Your program should work correctly with a different size and/or number of partitions.

You set a constant globally at the VERY TOP, as:

```java
final int N_PARTITIONS = 10;
```

and use it (`N_PARTITIONS`) throughout the program. your program should work even if the marker changes the value of `N_PARTITIONS` to 5 or 8 or 15 or ... (obviously, when N_PARTITIONS changes to 15, there should be 15 rows and 15 columns)

When you click anywhere on the display window, circle of diameter 10 (henceforth called a node) should be displayed at that point. Nodes from previous clicks should stay on the screen and there should be lines that join each node with the next one (and the last is joined to the first node). There should be no other lines besides these lines (and the grid lines of course).

There should be nodes drawn at the three points and lines from (200, 400) to (300, 300); (300, 300) to (60, 100); and (60, 100) to (200, 400).

Comment: no its in class work

Comment: sorry i don't understand you

Comment: Don't change the question title to 'no need for help anymore', removing the body, and asking others to remove comments. Mark that the answer proved to work by pressing the check icon under the downvote button.

Comment: We do not delete questions here where good help has been received. The answer below has an upvote, so you cannot delete the question. Moreover, we discourage "take and run" questions here - good question/answers are for posterity, not just the original question author.

Answer (score 3):

From how you desribed the expected output, it seems as if the grid lines and the nodes connected by lines are unrelated. Therefore, you have two tasks to accomplish:

1. Drawing a grid with `N_PARTITIONS` rows and column lines, and
2. Drawing and connecting circles of diameter 10 through a mouse-click.

The former is relatively easy. Given

```
final int N_PARTITIONS = 10;
```

we need 10 lines across the screen and 10 lines down the screen.

Within `void setup()`, use `size(600, 360);` to set the size of the canvas to 600x360 pixels.

---

Let's handle drawing lines across the screen first. We will use a `for` loop to accomplish this.

```
void draw() {
  int distVertLine = width / N_PARTITIONS; // This variable defines the distance between each subsequent vertical line.
  for(int i = distVertLine / 2; i < width; i += distVertLine) {

    line(i, 0, i, height); // Draw a line at x=i starting at the top of the canvas (y=0) and going to the bottom (y=height)
  }
}
```

Above, we initialize a `distVertLine` variable to define the horizontal distance between each vertical line. Its value is `width / N_PARTITIONS` because we are splitting up the width of the canvas into a given amount of partitions.

In the `for` loop, `i` is initialized as `distVertLine / 2` so that the grid lines are in the center.

Similarly, we can do this with the horizontal lines:

```
int distHorizLine = height / N_PARTITIONS; // This variable defines the distance between each subsequent vertical line.
for(int i = distHorizLine / 2; i < width; i += distHorizLine) {

  line(0, i, width, i); // Draw a line at y=i starting at the left of the canvas (x=0) and going to the right (x=width)
}
```

[image: The completed grid.]

---

Now for the nodes and lines. A circle in Processing is given by `circle(x, y, extent)` (check out the docs [here](https://processing.org/reference/circle_.html)).

When the mouse is pressed, the method `void mousePressed()` is called. Upon each press, we wish to record the `x` and `y` values in an array:

```
ArrayList nodeX = new ArrayList(); // ArrayLists are nice to use because they're expandable, unlike a Processing array.
ArrayList nodeY = new ArrayList(); // ArrayLists are nice to use because they're expandable, unlike a Processing array.

void mouseClicked() {
  nodeX.add(mouseX); // Adds the x-position of the mouse pointer to the nodeX list.
  nodeY.add(mouseY); // Adds the y-position of the mouse pointer to the nodeY list.
}
```

In `void draw()`, set up a `for` loop that draws circles at the coordinates in both lists:

```
stroke(0); // Set the circle's outline as black.
for(int i = 0; i < nodeX.size(); i++) {
  float xPos = (int)nodeX.get(i); // Grab the ith x-position from the list.
  float yPos = (int)nodeY.get(i); // Grab the ith y-position from the list.
  circle(xPos, yPos, 10);  // Draw a circle of diameter 10 at (xPos, yPos).
}
```

[image: The completed grid.]

(Note, within the first line of `void draw()` I added

```
background(255); // Set the background color to white
stroke(125); // Set the stroke color as gray.
```

to make it easier to see the circles).

---

Last, we need to connect each circle with a line.

```
stroke(0, 0, 255); // Make the connecting lines blue.
for(int i = 0; i < nodeX.size() - 1; i++) {
  float xPosA = (int)nodeX.get(i); // Grab the ith x-position from the list.
  float yPosA = (int)nodeY.get(i); // Grab the ith y-position from the list.
  float xPosB = (int)nodeX.get(i+1); // Grab the next x-position from the list.
  float yPosB = (int)nodeY.get(i+1); // Grab the next y-position from the list.
  line(xPosA, yPosA, xPosB, yPosB);
}
// And draw the connecting line.
if(nodeX.size() > 0) { // The code in this block will crash unless this condition is added to handle an empty list.
  int size = nodeX.size() - 1; // Get the index of the last item in nodeX/nodeY.
  float xPosA = (int)nodeX.get(0); // Grab the first x-position from the list.
  float yPosA = (int)nodeY.get(0); // Grab the first y-position from the list.
  float xPosB = (int)nodeX.get(size); // Grab the last x-position from the list.
  float yPosB = (int)nodeY.get(size); // Grab the last y-position from the list.
  line(xPosA, yPosA, xPosB, yPosB);
}
```

[image: The completed project when run.]